# Problema al obtener JSON de una pagina con android studios

Tags: android-studio, json, google-api

Buenas estoy intentando obtener el `json` de una pagina pero en vez de eso me sae todo el `html`

> Programa de android studios

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText campo_nombre_pj;
    Button btn_buscar_pj;
    String cosaBuscar = "";
    String mask_http = "https://playoverwatch.com/es-es/heroes/";
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        campo_nombre_pj = findViewById(R.id.campo_nombre_pj);
        btn_buscar_pj = findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar_pj);


        btn_buscar_pj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (campo_nombre_pj.getText().toString().trim().length() > 1) {
                    String nombrepj = campo_nombre_pj.getText().toString();
                cosaBuscar = nombrepj;
                 //   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
              /*         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_USER_BACKGROUND);

                    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, " https://playoverwatch.com/es-es/heroes/"+nombrepj+"/");
                    startActivity(intent);
*/
                    new JsonTask().execute(mask_http+nombrepj);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Campo vacio..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });








    }


    private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();


                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line+"\n");
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

                }

                return buffer.toString();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pd.isShowing()){
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            System.out.println("Resultado : "+result);
        }
    }
}
```

> Pero me devuelve esto

`

```
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="es-es"><head><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://d3hmvhl7ru3t12.cloudfront.net/img/favicon-bb6200267bbdea6fdc9eb498a88722007dad6eb3b3c6437440025c66cb055fefdd1fbedf3886bd069fc3547c79fa8afee4795a278a644f6cfe10a7b1144f48bb.ico"><title>Doomfist - Héroes - Overwatch</title><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"><meta itemprop="name" content="Doomfist - Overwatch"><meta itemprop="description" content="Doomfist es un estratega que utiliza su inteligencia, carisma y fuerza bruta para hacer que el mundo evolucione."><meta itemprop="image" content="https://d3hmvhl7ru3t12.cloudfront.net/img/share/heroes-c08aa560b2f9c15ffaaa5f81446e8902734065ba71b1251af24e150857bc2f8d57bea402102296978eacde2577a33bafe813511f382c330356ce33f4204405ed.jpg"><link rel="canonical" href="https://playoverwatch.com/es-es/heroes/doomfist"><!--Opengraph Tags - http://ogp.me/--><meta property="og:type" content="website"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Overwatch"><meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES"><meta property="og:title" content="Doomfist - Overwatch"><meta property="og:description" content="Doomfist es un estratega que utiliza su inteligencia, carisma y fuerza bruta para hacer que el mundo evolucione."><meta property="og:image" content="https://d3hmvhl7ru3t12.cloudfront.net/img/share/heroes-c08aa560b2f9c15ffaaa5f81446e8902734065ba71b1251af24e150857bc2f8d57bea402102296978eacde2577a33bafe813511f382c330356ce33f4204405ed.jpg"><meta property="og:url" content="https://playoverwatch.com/es-es/heroes/doomfist"><script type='text/javascript'>window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"agent":"","beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"fbd2e57ca0","applicationID":"57833303","applicationTime":14.391382,"transactionName":"b1NWY0MFDUpQWxIIXVYZcU9BFgZKQlIVTnV9YhsYWQERVlRLSVtbXA==","queueTime":0,"ttGuid":"726ed206e6fff0","agentToken":null}; (window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VQEHV1RWCRAFU1lRBAIHVQ=="};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o||e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({1:[function(t,e,n){function r(t){try{c.console&&console.log(t)}catch(e){}}var o,i=t("ee"),a=t(20),c={};try{o=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"function"==typeof console.log&&(c.console=!0,o.indexOf("dev")!==-1&&(c.dev=!0),o.indexOf("nr_dev")!==-1&&(c.nrDev=!0))}catch(s){}c.nrDev&&i.on("internal-error",function(t){r(t.stack)}),c.dev&&i.on("fn-err",function(t,e,n){r(n.stack)}),c.dev&&(r("NR AGENT IN DEVELOPMENT MODE"),r("flags: "+a(c,function(t,e){return t}).join(", ")))},{}],2:[function(t,e,n){function r(t,e,n,r,c){try{h?h-=1:o(c||new UncaughtException(t,e,n),!0)}catch(f){try{i("ierr",[f,s.now(),!0])}catch(d){}}return"function"==typeof u&&u.apply(this,a(arguments))}function UncaughtException(t,e,n){this.message=t||"Uncaught error with no additional information",this.sourceURL=e,this.line=n}function o(t,e){var n=e?null:s.now();i("err",[t,n])}var i=t("handle"),a=t(21),c=t("ee"),s=t("loader"),f=t("gos"),u=window.onerror,d=!1,p="nr@seenError",h=0;s.features.err=!0,t(1),window.onerror=r;try{throw new Error}catch(l){"stack"in l&&(t(13),t(12),"addEventListener"in window&&t(6),s.xhrWrappable&&t(14),d=!0)}c.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){d&&(h+=1)}),c.on("fn-err",function(t,e,n){d&&!n[p]&&(f(n,p,function(){return!0}),this.thrown=!0,o(n))}),c.on("fn-end",function(){d&&!this.thrown&&h>0&&(h-=1)}),c.on("internal-error",function(t){i("ierr",[t,s.now(),!0])})},{}],3:[function(t,e,n){t("loader").features.ins=!0},{}],4:[function(t,e,n){function r(){M++,S=y.hash,this[u]=b.now()}function o(){M--,y.hash!==S&&i(0,!0);var t=b.now();this[l]=~~this[l]+t-this[u],this[d]=t}function i(t,e){E.emit("newURL",[""+y,e])}function a(
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: >     background-image:url(https://d1u1mce87gyfbn.cloudfront.net/hero/doomfist/background-story.jpg);
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: >     background-color:;
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: >     
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: >     background-position: 80% top;
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > }
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > .hero-pose-image {
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: >     background-image:url(https://d1u1mce87gyfbn.cloudfront.net/hero/doomfist/full-portrait.png);
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > }
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > </style><script src="https://cdn.optimizely.com/js/8304241110.js"></script><script>var clientVars = {"language":"es","urlLocale":"es-es","locale":"es_ES","loggedIn":false,"region":"us","serverRegion":"us","codeFile":"https://d3hmvhl7ru3t12.cloudfront.net/video/dva-code-3782ae17f615dbd4de7063d9b08bddeea7c756ce8992e3de89ccbb620e00c4df2afd6a9009f0334098dd681fc61fa785be5d6c2dea448482eb93d914cd18fc54.mp3"};
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > 
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > window.blizzard = window.blizzard || {};
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > Object.keys(clientVars).forEach(function(key) {
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: >     window.blizzard[key] = clientVars[key];
06-01 16:05:48.186 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > });</script></head><body itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" class="hero-detail-page es-es"><script>var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > dataLayer.push({"locale":"es-ES","region":"us","project":"overwatch","authenticated":"0","localeRegion":"eu"});
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > </script><noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TT34VR" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript><script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', 'GTM-TT34VR');
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > </script><script>!function(i,d,e,n){i[e]=i[e]||{},i[e][n]||(i[e][n]=function(i,e,n){if(void 0!==i){e=void 0===e?0:e,n=void 0===n?0:n;var a=d.createElement("iframe");a.width=e,a.height=n,a.hidden=!0,a.src=i,d.body.appendChild(a)}})}(window,document,"analytics","appendFrame");</script><div id="navbar" class="navbars"><div data-region="eu" data-locale="es-es" data-hash="5fa0a9ec7c8b160b81e2c9c81792d7976df4bffa" data-service-type="l" data-service-endpoint="P" data-service-version="3.3.3" data-middleware-version="3.3.1" data-ajax data-auth-url="/navbar/authenticate" data-notification-url="/navbar/notifications" data-support-url="https://eu.battle.net/support/update/json?callback=" data-current-site="games" class="Navbar is-compact is-auto is-custom-logo"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="Navbar-embedded"><g id="Navbar-icon-new_window">
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > <path d="M21.737,39.117c3.938-6.052,8.981-10.014,19.089-10.014v7.024L53.708,24.95   L40.826,13.77v6.72C26.135,20.489,21.737,32.97,21.737,39.117L21.737,39.117z"/>
06-01 16:05:48.187 19445-19710/com.example.josel.inspiracion_manolo D/Response:: > <path d="M48.792,35.739V47.23c0,0.276-0.224,0.5-0.5,0.5h-35c-0.276,0-0.5-0.224-0.5-0.5v-26
```

> que es en definitiva todo el html de la pagina, que es lo que tengo que poner para que me devuelva solo html de la pagina ?
>   lo que me interesaria es conseguir al gomo  : nombre de persoaje: doomfist,
>   etc...

Comment: Para obtener los datos en JSON tendrás que hacer peticiones [a la API de la página](https://dev.battle.net/io-docs). Según parece para tener acceso tendrás que registrarte y leer la documentación sobre cómo codificar la URL  de petición a la API, incluyendo tu clave de API. El código Android también tendrás que cambiarlo, a un código que reciba un JSON y puedas luego leerlo. Para eso recomendaría que uses Volley, una vez tengas acceso a la API.

Comment: oye muchas gracias, no recordaba eso. El tema es que el spinner que te da a elegir entre los tipos de API , ninguno pone OW ( Overwatch) , pone wow y otras cosas que claro no se cual es el que debo elegir, se cual no: el del WOW . Pero ya te digo me has ayudado bastante con eso @A.Cedano

Comment: Me alegro de que mi comentario haya servido de algo. Creo que como un primer paso tendrías que informarte con ellos, (en la documentación o a través de soporte técnico), cuál es la forma correcta de consultar su API... cómo tienes que escribir la URL y cómo tienes que poner la clave de API. También tendrían que decirte cómo responde la API (es por lo general un JSON). Sabido eso, en un segundo paso tendrás que modificar tu código Android, poniendo la URL correcta, y preparar dicho código para recibir / leer la respuesta en el formato en que la API responda (JSON u otro).